# How to sum two lists of tuples

Tags: python

```
list1 = [(1533945600000, 140), (1534032000000, 412), (1534118400000, 364), (1534204800000, 488), (1534291200000, 272), (1534377600000, 350), (1534464000000, 301), (1534550400000, 159), (1534636800000, 224), (1534723200000, 241), (1534809600000, 223), (1534896000000, 175)]


list2 = [(1533945600000, 1516), (1534032000000, 2176), (1534118400000, 2046), (1534204800000, 2400), (1534291200000, 8370), (1534377600000, 2112), (1534464000000, 1441), (1534550400000, 784), (1534636800000, 1391), (1534723200000, 1178), (1534809600000, 1020), (1534896000000, 795)]
```

How could you combine them into a single list of tuples? considering the first value of the key appears in both lists.

Comment: Can you explain more? Not exactly sure if you just want to combine the two lists or something more.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to add the second items in each tuple but leave the first the same? Your first item being (1533945600000, 1656)? Have you done any work with tuples before?

Comment: @LioElbammalf yes, it would be to sum the second value leaving the first value the same

Comment: Can you post what the output should look like? I.E what would you see after `print(output)`

Comment: @lapinkoira does the order of 1st value of tuples can be different in list1 and list2?

Comment: Its solved in the answers, though it was clear enough tho, thanks

Comment: @SandeepKadapa no, they should be the same

Comment: @lapinkoira can you accept if my solution helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `zip` on list1,list2 and then add second value of each tuple:

```
lst = []
for tup1,tup2 in zip(list1,list2):
    sum_ = tup1[1]+tup2[1]
    lst.append((tup1[0],sum_))

lst

[(1533945600000, 1656),
 (1534032000000, 2588),
 (1534118400000, 2410),
 (1534204800000, 2888),
 (1534291200000, 8642),
 (1534377600000, 2462),
 (1534464000000, 1742),
 (1534550400000, 943),
 (1534636800000, 1615),
 (1534723200000, 1419),
 (1534809600000, 1243),
 (1534896000000, 970)]
```

Comment: This answer makes several assumptions that might be inappropriate:
1. The lists have the same length.
2. The tuples have the same keys in both lists.
3. The tuples are in the same order in both lists.

Comment: @AgostBiro My assumptions are correct as per OP's comment.

Comment: Since these assumptions aren't clear from the question, my comment was meant as warning for other people trying to solve the same problem.

Comment: @AgostBiro I appreciate your comment. It is just that my assumptions met expectations of OP.  Thank you.

Comment: @AgostBiro What would you do in case of 2. The tuples have the same keys in both lists being a false assumption?

Comment: @JürgenK. check out my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51983983

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following snippet if the lists are not guaranteed to have the same length or the keys are not guaranteed to be present in both lists or they are not in the same order:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = [(1533945600000, 140), (1534032000000, 412), (1534118400000, 364), (1534204800000, 488), (1534291200000, 272), (1534377600000, 350), (1534464000000, 301), (1534550400000, 159), (1534636800000, 224), (1534723200000, 241), (1534809600000, 223), (1534896000000, 175)]
list2 = [(1533945600000, 1516), (1534032000000, 2176), (1534118400000, 2046), (1534204800000, 2400), (1534291200000, 8370), (1534377600000, 2112), (1534464000000, 1441), (1534550400000, 784), (1534636800000, 1391), (1534723200000, 1178), (1534809600000, 1020), (1534896000000, 795)]

d = defaultdict(int, list1)
for key, n in list2:                   
    d[key] += n
res = list(map(tuple, d.items()))
```

res:

```
[(1533945600000, 1656),
 (1534032000000, 2588),
 (1534118400000, 2410),
 (1534204800000, 2888),
 (1534291200000, 8642),
 (1534377600000, 2462),
 (1534464000000, 1742),
 (1534550400000, 943),
 (1534636800000, 1615),
 (1534723200000, 1419),
 (1534809600000, 1243),
 (1534896000000, 970)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `List comprehension` with `zip` :

```
>>> [(x[0], x[1]+y[1]) for x,y in zip(list1, list2)]
```

#driver values :

```
IN : list1 = [(1533945600000, 140), (1534032000000, 412), (1534118400000, 364), (1534204800000, 488), (1534291200000, 272), (1534377600000, 350), (1534464000000, 301), (1534550400000, 159), (1534636800000, 224), (1534723200000, 241), (1534809600000, 223), (1534896000000, 175)]
     list2 = [(1533945600000, 1516), (1534032000000, 2176), (1534118400000, 2046), (1534204800000, 2400), (1534291200000, 8370), (1534377600000, 2112), (1534464000000, 1441), (1534550400000, 784), (1534636800000, 1391), (1534723200000, 1178), (1534809600000, 1020), (1534896000000, 795)]

OUT : [(1533945600000, 1656), (1534032000000, 2588), (1534118400000, 2410), (1534204800000, 2888), (1534291200000, 8642), (1534377600000, 2462), (1534464000000, 1742), (1534550400000, 943), (1534636800000, 1615), (1534723200000, 1419), (1534809600000, 1243), (1534896000000, 970)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
combined_list=[]
for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
     combined_list.append((i[0]+j[0],i[1]+j[1]))
```